# Why is the value of $\int_0^{2\pi}|2\cos(nx)+\sqrt{3}|\,dx$ independent of integer parameter $n$?

Tags: trigonometry, definite-integrals, absolute-value

I am not able to find an easy solution for the following formula

$$\int_0^{2\pi}|2\cos(nx)+\sqrt{3}|dx=4+\frac{4}{3}\pi\sqrt{3}.$$

Please help me  prove it. Why it does not depend on the (positive) integer parameter $n$?

Comment: Hint 1: break it up. Find out where the function is negative and make it positive. You'll have a few more integrals but from there you don't have absolute values. Hint 2: cosine is an even function. I think this will help ...

Comment: Thank you for your hint. This would be the obvious way to proceed. But it will require hard work. Actually I am looking for a simpler solution which will give the answer to my last question: why it does not depend on $n$? It seems that the same is true for the modulus of any polynomial in $\cos(nx)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline:** We address only the independence from the positive integer parameter $n$. Let $f(x)=|2\cos x+\sqrt{3}|$.

$1$) Show that for any $k$ between $0$ and $n-1$ 
$$\int_{2\pi k/n}^{2\pi(k+1)/n}f(nx)\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi/n} f(nx)\,dx.$$
This is done by a change of variable.

$2$) Show that 
$$\int_0^{2\pi/n} f(nx)\,dx=\frac{1}{n}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)\,dx.$$
This is also done by a change of variable.

**Remark:** More informally, because of the periodicity of $f$, the integral breaks up naturally into a sum of $n$ equal parts. Each of the $n$ "areas" is $\frac{1}{n}$ of $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx$, because we are scaling in the $x$-direction by the factor $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: This is a very nice answer. And it uses only the periodicity of f. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, we can replace what I called $f(x)$ by any function that has $2\pi$ as a period. The idea is basically geometric.